# how to keep WPF UserControl loaded and use HwndSource (problem with Exception : The root Visual of Visual Target cannot have a parent)

Tags: c#, wpf, interop

I created UserControl and display it in external window. That means I created plugin and it is used in host application (not created by me) which display that WPF UserControl as GUI.

Everything is working, I can **reopen window** and it is **ok**, except

### The Problem

when window is recreated by host application. That means, when is double clicked on window, host application change **window** (is **recreated quickly**) and add own (host application) panel inside window. Then **I get this exception:**

> System.ArgumentException: The root Visual of Visual Target cannot have a parent
>
> ...
>
> at mf_GetViewIP(IntPtr& view) in App.Xaml.csline 78

Here is code how I display WPF USerControl

```
private void mf_GetViewIP(ref IntPtr view)
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_main_view == null) 
                {         
                    m_main_view = new Views.uc_main_view();
                    m_main_view.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    m_main_view.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                }

                sourceParam = new HwndSourceParameters("Arpegissimo ML");
                sourceParam.PositionX = 0;
                sourceParam.PositionY = 0;
                sourceParam.ParentWindow = view;
                sourceParam.WindowStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD;
                
                source = new HwndSource(sourceParam);
                source.RootVisual = m_main_view; // csline 78 (exception)

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
            if (mfp_wai_set != null)
            {
                mfp_wai_set();
            }
        }
```

the **exception dissapear when** `if (m_main_view == null)` is **deleted** and `m_main_view` is allways `new`
and this is what I want to avoid it.

---

### Question

How to keep `m_main_view` (not use everytime `new`) without getting this exception? Is it possible? I just want avoid to everytime load and prepare my view when GUI is displayed second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
    private void mf_GetViewIP(ref IntPtr view)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m_main_view == null) 
            {         
                m_main_view = new Views.uc_main_view();
                m_main_view.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                m_main_view.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            }

            if (source != null)
            {
                source.Dispose(); // need to clear hold old reference to m_main_view
            }

            sourceParam = new HwndSourceParameters("Arpegissimo ML");
            sourceParam.PositionX = 0;
            sourceParam.PositionY = 0;
            sourceParam.ParentWindow = view;
            sourceParam.WindowStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD;

            source = new HwndSource(sourceParam);
            source.RootVisual = m_main_view;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        if (mfp_wai_set != null)
        {
            mfp_wai_set();
        }
    }
```

I think when host application recreate window, it happend so quickly, that is not so quick (from WPF side) to delete it from `HwndSource` (becuase when windows is reopen manualy it is without exception), therefore it is need call to `HwndSource.Dispose()`.